# How to prevent mass assignments on associations the right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

Let's say i have a model `Warehouse`, a model `Car`, and a model `Dealer`.

model `Car` is like:

```
attr_accessible :make, :year
belongs_to :warehouse
belongs_to :dealer
```

controller `Cars` is like:

```
def create
  car = current_dealer.find(params[:car][:warehouse_id]).cars.new(params[:car])
  car.save!
end
```

the view of `Cars#new` is like:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @car do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :warehouse, :include_blank => false %>
    <%= f.input :make %>
    <%= f.input :year %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Dealers can choose a warehouse when adding a car, The above code is protected against mass assignments *(a.k.a. dealers adding cars to warehouses they don't own)*, But it raises an exception saying `:warehouse_id` cannot be mass assigned, That's because it's brought with the parameters too as `params[:car][:warehouse_id]`.

How to get rid of that error without manually assigning attributes? And is that a good method anyways?

P.S. i tried `params[:car].delete(:warehouse_id)` but that doesn't look like the right way to do this.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want a Car's `warehouse` to be mass assignable or not?

Comment: @varatis No, that shouldn't be. Only :make and :year can be mass assigned.

Comment: Can you post the view associated with this create action? It seems like you're trying to assign it from the form, which is antithetical to disallowing mass assignment.

Comment: @varatis, the view is pretty standard formtastic, like: `<%= semantic_form_for @car do |f| %><%= f.inputs do %><%= f.input :warehouse, :include_blank => false %>` ...

Comment: Yeah, see the problem -- you're saying `form_for @car`, and trying to assign one of its attributes (warehouse). That's mass-assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Since :warehouse_id is not a mass-assignable attribute of car, you can't post it from a form as an attribute of car. Rails will raise the mass-assignment error if you name your params in such a manner even if you do nothing with them in the controller.

Rather than doing (non formtastic specific):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :warehouse_id %>
```

do:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :warehouse_id, @car.warehouse_id %>
```

I'm not too familiar with formtastic, but I would think the above line should work.

In the controller:

```
def create
  @car = current_dealer.find(params[:warehouse_id]).cars.new(params[:car])
  @warehouse = Warehouse.find(params[:warehouse_id])
  @car.warehouse = @warehouse
  @car.save!
end
```

It's a little more tedious, I know. Unfortunately, securing your code requires more effort.

**Conclusion**:
`params[:car][:warehouse_id]` = mass assignment

Comment: But how am i supposed to let dealers choose which one of their warehouses they want to add the car to?

Comment: Well Formtastic sends `warehouse_id` as `params[:car][:warehouse_id]` so that's the issue.

Comment: That is indeed the issue. I'm not too familiar with that particular plugin, but you'll have to change how that variable is passed :(

Comment: @tybro0103 is correct. If you need the warehouse selectable, just change the `hidden_field_tag` into a `select_tag` with the appropriate values. The key is that you need a stand-alone tag and can't use your form builder, since that is for the car model.

Answer (score 1):

**Stop using attr_accessible, use [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/)**

Remove `attr_accessible :make, :year`

Add `gem 'strong_parameters'` to your Gemfile.

Add `include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` to your each of your models.

Then, replace:

```
car = current_dealer.find(params[:car][:warehouse_id]).cars.new(params[:car])
```

with:

```
car = current_dealer.find(params[:car][:warehouse_id]).cars.new(params.require(:car).permit([:make, :year]))
```

Comment: Sounds like this will be baked into Rails 4. There's RailsCast on it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters I probably wouldn't completely remove attr_accessible just yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Mass Assignment determines only if a field can be set or not through a form (or API), it does not control what can be set. The problem is you are trying to use mass assignment to control validation or restriction of data. In your case you want to be able to save a `warehouse_id` through a user selected pick list therefore it must be available for mass assignment to use the standard params approach to creating a car.

A suggested solution would be to first use the Formtastic `select` input to restrict the values that a dealer may select. Although I don't know how you currently restrict warehouses the general version is:

```
f.input :warehouse, :as => :select, :collection => "Whatever your selection rule is"
```

This should ensure that only the list of Warehouses that are available to a dealer are actually show in the form.

This doesn't solve the issue a person with enough technical knowledge could change the warehouse_id in the URL and still post to a warehouse that they do not own. So you should also add a validation on the Car model which would ensure that only warehouses belonging to the dealer were valid selections.

This should solve your issue, leave the mass assignment in place for warehouse_id, which you need, while still ensuring that a dealer can only choose a warehouse that belongs to them.